# post request to axios gave 500 error in laravel

Tags: javascript, php, html, laravel, axios

I have problem in my project when is use Axios on post method  but when I use get method in Axios and change Route::post to Route::get it actually work .

and error is : Request failed with status code 500 ;

> and in server error is : signUp?signUp?full_name=&user_name=&email=&mobile=&password=&send=:64     POST http://192.168.1.4:8070/user/create 500 (Internal Server Error)

how can I fixe that

routing in Laravel:

```
Route::group(["as" => "user_", "prefix" => "user"], function () {
    Route::get('/signIn', [HomeController::class, 'signIn'])->name('signIn');
    Route::get('/signUp', [HomeController::class, 'signUp'])->name('signUp');
    Route::post("/create",[UserController::class , "store"])->name("create");
});
```

Javascript:

```
<script>
    var getForms = document.getElementsByClassName('form-control');
    function submitForm(e) {
        axios.post('/user/create', {
            full_name : getForms[0],
            user_name : getForms[1],
            email : getForms[2],
            mobile : getForms[3],
            password : getForms[4],
        })
            .then(function (response) {
                console.log(response);
            })
            .catch(function (error) {
                console.log(error);
            });
        e.preventDefault();
    }
</script>
```

controller

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $full_name = $request->full_name;
    $user_name = $request->user_name;
    $email = $request->email;
    $mobile = $request->mobile;
    $password = $request->password;

    $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
        'first_name' => 'required|max:255',
        'last_name' => 'required|max:255',
        'email' => 'required',
    ]);

    if ($validator->fails()) {
        return response()->json(['errors' => $validator->errors()], 422);
    }

    $user = userAuth::query()->create([
        "full_name" => $full_name,
        "user_name" => $user_name,
        "email" => $email,
        "mobile" => $mobile,
        "password" => $password,
    ]);

    return response()->json([
        'user' => $user,
        'message' => 'Success'
    ], 200);
}
```

Comment: A 500 error is a generic error message and covers pretty much every single thing that can go wrong with a PHP script. Check your server error logs to find out the exact error message. For Laravel, also check in `storage/logs`

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is with your route order please move you `post` method route on the top and the `get` method route to the bottom. I faced that problem many times.

Solution Example:

```
Route::group(["as" => "user_", "prefix" => "user"], function () {
    Route::post("/create",[UserController::class , "store"])->name("create");
    Route::get('/signIn', [HomeController::class, 'signIn'])->name('signIn');
    Route::get('/signUp', [HomeController::class, 'signUp'])->name('signUp');
});
```

***also, try to remove the cache using,***

```
php artisan optimize:clear
```

I hope that will help you.

Comment: There aren't any wildcards routes and they all have different route paths, so the order shouldn't be an issue.